# Open file using AppleScript in Word 2016

Tags: ms-word, applescript

The following Applescript code works (i.e. opens the document, provided it exists) with Word 2008.

It does not work with Word 2016 if the application is not already running.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    open file "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Stuff.docx"
end tell
```

Word 2016 opens a dialog saying that the file does not exist, then creates and opens a file in the following directory:

```
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data
```

That file’s name appears as follows in the Finder:

```
Macintosh HD/Users/username/Stuff.docx
```

And as follows in the Terminal:

```
~$cintosh HD:Users:edimark:Rien.docx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `launch` or `activate`. I can’t explain why this is needed, though.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
   launch
   open file "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Stuff.docx"
end tell
```

`activate` will bring the app to the front; `launch` won’t.

Comment: Generally speaking, for AppleScript to use an app, it must be running.  Obviously, "activate" ensures the app is running before you try to use it.

Comment: Why wouldn’t `tell` suffice? Also, Word does launch whether I use `activate` or not – it just messes things up if I don’t.

Comment: @JMichaelTX – See my comment to @brandelune’s answer. Providing a means to explicitly launch an app is welcome, but making it mandatory where the need to launch is obvious would be, for a supposedly high-level user-friendly language, unwelcome.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Word used to work with just a tell and without being activated is a problem with Word, not AppleScript.

As was replied earlier, using launch or activate is a requirement for AppleScript to properly send a message to the application.

Comment: Any source about that?  
  
Safari, iTunes, Automator, Instruments, Grab, Terminal, InDesign CS6, InCopy CS6 also launch with a simple tell and open script, without `launch` or `activate`. (Tested with macOS 10.12.)

Comment: AppleScript Language Guide, p. 261
"A tell statement that targets a local application doesn’t cause it to launch, if it is not already running. For example, a script can examine the running property of the targeted application (page 100) object to determine if the application is running before attempting to send it any commands. If it is not running it won’t be launched."

Also here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-157872

Comment: *Next paragraph:* “If a `tell` statement targets a local application and executes any statements that require a response from the application, then AppleScript will launch the application if it is not already running. The application is launched as hidden, but the script can send it an `activate` command to bring it to the front, if needed.”

Comment: My bad ! I've always used *activate* to make sure I would not have error when targeting an app (along with a *try* block).

Have you tried to see the errors when you launch that in Script Debugger?

Comment: Well, I resort to AppleScript as little as I can, and I’m not familiar with the debugger… As my problem is solved, I’m not inclined to do further research.